# Use RANK function for cell range based on criteria in separate cell range

Tags: excel, excel-2010, rank

I have a question regarding the RANK function in MS Excel 2010. I have a large worksheet whose rows I want to rank based on the values in a column. These values can be positive or negative. I found helpful advice [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/303127-ranking-positive-negative-but-not-zeros.html) which explains how to rank the values in a column while excluding all values that equal zero from the ranking and the ranking count. They use the following formula:

```
IF(O24<0, RANK(O24,$O$24:$O$29) - COUNTIF($O$24:$O$29,0), IF(O24=0, "", RANK(O24,$O$24:$O$29)))
```

This works great, but it would be even better if I could rank the values only if a corresponding value in the same row but a different column meets certain criteria.

Is something like this possible and how would I do it? How would I update the example formula above to make the change work? Thank you very much in advance for your help.

P.S.: I tried putting in a table but it didn't really work, sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `COUNTIFS` function to rank based on a condition in another column, e.g. this formula in row 24 copied down [edited to include extra IF)

`=IF(O24=0,"",IF(N24="x",COUNTIFS(O$24:O$29,">"&O24,O$24:O$29,"<>0",N$24:N$29,"x")+1,""))`

That will rank high to low where column N = "x", ignoring zero values

See [this example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jbprbp6arwtlbj6/rank_example.xlsx) columns N and O contain random values - press F9 to re-generate new random values and formula results in column Q will change accordingly

Comment: Thank you, this looks very interesting, but I couldn't get it to work yet. Say I don't want to exclude zero values, but only ranked based on row N. I only want to rank values in row O if the corresponding value in row N is >10. How would I update your formula then?

Comment: Sorry, that wouldn't quite work as written (you need an extra IF) try this version for your suggestion `=IF(N24>10,COUNTIFS(O$24:O$29,">"&O24,N$24:N$29,">10")+1,"")`

Comment: Yay, cool! This works now in that it returns a "1" for every value in row O that contains a value >10 in row N. But how I would I now go about ranking these remaining cells based on their values in row O?

Comment: Are you using that formula exactly? (I needed to edit) It shouldn't return 1 for each row, it should rank the values (COUNTIFS is effectively ranking), I'll try to attach an example......

Comment: Ahhh, no, I forgot to include the second ">10". I'm sorrryy, thank youuu, I think now it's working perfectly!!!

Comment: I attached an example link in my answer above - RANK function is only really a version of COUNTIF, counting how many numbers in a range are greater than a specific number, COUNTIFS lets you add more conditions, so the COUNTIFS function itself is ranking with a condition

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I didn't know that before. As I said, I overlooked an error on my part that I fixed and now it works to perfection!! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible to keep creating more complex formulas whenever you're adding new criteria on which to rank.  However by creating intermediary columns with single-step formulas, you'll make your spreadsheet easier to comprehend and easier to add new criteria or edit the existing.

My suggestion is to create a column that excludes the zero's (let's assume this is in column P): `=IF(O24 = 0, "", O24)`

Then in column R, to eliminate negative values (this step is unnecessary, but your original formula does something similar): `=IF(P24 = "", "", P24 - MIN(0, MIN($O$24:$O$29)))`

Now in column S, add your newest criteria: `=IF(OR(R24="", [enter newest criteria here]), "", R24)`

Finally, column T performs the ranking of only the selected rows: `=IF(S24="", "", RANK(S24, S$24:S$29))`

If exposing columns P, R and S is bothersome, you can always hide them.

Comment: Thank you! I'd rather keep the whole formula in one row, however, if possible. Is there a way to combine your formula into one so I can try it on my Excel sheet?

Comment: The point of my response is that combining all those formulas into a single cell is a poor idea.  You are better off splitting each part into its own formula.  This aids maintainability, comprehension, and simplifies future editing.

Answer (score 0):

A rewording of the answer from barry houdini, using table format.
Value_Col is the column with the values to rank.  Group_Column is the column with the group by values, to rank within groups

=COUNTIFS([Value_Col], ">"&[@[Value]],    [Value_Column],"<>0",    [Group_Column], [@[Group]]) +1